# Can I recover Eclipse files after mac crashed? (Autosave was on!)

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, crash, recovery

I worked for 2+ hours in Eclipse with the Autosave feature on, every 5 minutes. I reboot my computer, and all of my files are yesterday's versions. Can I recover the autosaves from today?

Comment: Just to clarify, but are you referring to the eclipse-specific files (like the workspace setting file) or your actual source code files?

Comment: Source code files. I checked my workspace too, they are all yesterday's files

Comment: Where did you find the autosave feature? `Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Workspace save interval`?

Comment: Yes. It was set to 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

That setting just saves the state of the workspace, and not the actual code. One way you might be able to get your code back is by going to the local history with `right click -> Team -> Show Local History`.

Comment: it was empty. no files.

Comment: @user2827214 Then it appears that your files are completely lost. Sorry.